convert the .json file back to .jsonlz4 file as it was in Firefox
Hello every professional engineer
I knew how to convert the Firefox file sessionstore.jsonlz4 to .json file by using this website https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html
and after editing the resulting .json file
How can I convert it back to .jsonlz4 file to return it to my Firefox profile as it was?
Thank you very much I hope our science put us in excellent state

You will have to write your own tool.
